# What property can be checked on local schemes $Y\times_X\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_{X,x})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a $X$-scheme. For $x\in X$, we define the local scheme as the base change $Y\times_X\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_{X,x})$.

I have some questions about this local scheme:

1. What property can be checked on local schemes? (I mean property $P$ holds for every local scheme implies it holds for $f$)
2. Is there general relation between stalks of $Y\times_X\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_{X,x})$ and stalks of $X,Y$?
3. What's the intuitive difference between local scheme and fiber?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: about your first question, there are many properties that are local on target(In fact almost all useful properties our this way), so the question is when you can spread out this property from a local scheme to a neighborhood, for this check out the table at the end of the book rational points on varieties by poonen for a list of properties.(I think there is a free version available on author homepage)

Comment: About 3: For $x:Spec ~k(x)\to X$, there is a closed immersion $f^{-1}(y)=Y\times_X Spec ~k(x)\hookrightarrow Y\times_X Spec ~\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$. Intuitively (if I dare to suggest) $Y\times_X Spec~ \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ is a limit of neighbourhoods of $f^{-1}(y)$ in $Y$.

Comment: @EvansGambit It’s more like a limit over neighborhoods of $f^{-1}(y)$ which come from pullback of neighborhoods of $y$. This doesn’t necessarily equate to the limit over neighborhoods of $f^{-1}(y)$ (e.g. think about the projection map $\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{A}^1$) and this equality has something to do (intuitively) with the properness of $f$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Is there any reference for properties of local schemes?

Comment: @Hydrogen I’m not quote sure what you mean. References for properteis of $f$ that can be deduced by properties when base changed back to each local ring? Have you tried looking at the section on ‘spreading out’ in Poonen’s book on rational points on varieties?

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "What property can be checked on local schemes? (I mean property P holds for every local scheme implies it holds for f) Is there general relation between stalks of $Y×_X Spec(O_{X,x})$
and stalks of $X,Y$? What's the intuitive difference between local scheme and fiber?"

**Answer:** Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a map of commutative unital rings with $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq A, \mathfrak{p}\subseteq B$ prime ideals where $\mathfrak{p}\cap A=\mathfrak{q}$. There are canonical maps

$$B \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak{q}} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak{p}}$$

and

$$B \rightarrow C:=\kappa(\mathfrak{q})\otimes_A B \rightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak{q})\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{q}}}B_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$

**Question:** "What's the intuitive difference between local scheme and fiber?"

The local scheme is the spectrum $Spec(C_{\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}})$ of the local ring of the fiber ring $\kappa(\mathfrak{q})\otimes_A B$ at $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$: There is a prime ideal $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}} \subseteq C$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$ and an isomorphism

$$C_{\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}}\cong  \kappa(\mathfrak{q})\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{q}}}B_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{q}}B_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$

Hence the local ring of the fiber ring $C$ at $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a quotient of the local ring $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$. They both have the same residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$.

**Answer:** Hence the local scheme $Spec(\kappa(\mathfrak{q})\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{q}}}B_{\mathfrak{p}})$ is the spectrum of the local ring of the fiber ring $C$ at $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$. You get a sequence of maps

$$\kappa(\mathfrak{q}) \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{q}}B_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak{p}).$$

**Lemma:** If $A \rightarrow B$ with $B:=A[t_1,..,t_n]/(f_1,..,f_l)$ it follows
$\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_{B_{\mathfrak{p}}} \kappa(\mathfrak{p})=0$ iff

the canonical map $\kappa(\mathfrak{q}) \subseteq B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{q}}B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a finite separable extension of fields. There is an isomorphism

$$ B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{q}}B_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \kappa(\mathfrak{p}).$$

**Proof:** Theorem 3.1, Demazure/Gabriel - "Groupes algebriques".

**Question:** "What property can be checked on local schemes?"

**Answer:** You use the local scheme to define the notions "etale morphism " and "smooth morphisms".